# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while trying to use pytesseract

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python script to extract the text from image and i keep getting this error. The script is given below. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qanga.jpg)

```
from PIL import Image

from pytesseract import image_to_string

print (image_to_string(Image.open('samp.png')))

print (image_to_string(Image.open('test-english.jpg'), lang='eng'))
```

Comment: Please write the error into the question.

Comment: 'samp.png' needs to be in the same directory as your script. Or you need to change the path you are trying to open.

Comment: @andyhasit it is in the same directory.

Comment: Which directory? The error log shows that you were in "rahul_pappu" tried to run "a.py" which wasn't found, then cd'd to desktop. I'm guessing "samp.png" is in  "rahul_pappu". If not, run the "dir" command, or please provide screenshot to show that the script is in same directory as png files.

Comment: Ps: have you specified the path to tesseract exe, as per docs: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract

Comment: @andyhasit the samp.png is in the desktop and the script is also in the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps, this worked for me.

1) Download tesseract-OCR from [here](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_tesseract-ocr-alt/downloads/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.00.exe/) and install it in the location `C:/Program Files`

2)write the following code

```
from PIL import Image

from pytesseract import image_to_string
```

`#pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'`
i.e

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

3)Now run this

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('D:/image_file.jpg')))
```

Hope that help!